# Converting a string to JSON (unexpected token u/')

Tags: javascript, json

Simple question, why doesnt this work? It throws 'unexpected token'!

```js
var example = "{'form_id':'foo','title':'bar'}";

console.log(JSON.parse(example));
```

Comment: JSON wants double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: You can also try `JSON.parse('{"form_id": "foo", "title": "bar" }')`

Comment: Thank you, this works now with your guidance. Post it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem are the quotes. In this link you can read about this ([https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx)

Your code should be the following:

```
var example = '{"form_id":"foo","title":"bar"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(example));
```